# React native app white screen in Samsung Galaxy M20

Tags: android, react-native, apk, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

I generated an APK for my app with expo:build android. It works fine in my One plus. Also tried in a couple of other Samsung Galaxy devices. It works there as well. But my client uses a Samsung Galaxy M20 and seems to be getting a white screen. Now I do not have access to this device. I tried to find an emulator for this particular device but haven't found one yet. It worked successfully in every other devices that I tried it in (Nexus, Pixel). Anyone faced a similar issue?

Here's a link to the APK if that helps 
https://expo.io/artifacts/95f608b5-472f-4146-9775-f1998d98ce7a

I am new to this and I'm not even sure how to debug this issue. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It could be a problem in your screen style and design. Plz share your tried code for screen render

Comment: @Aditi Have you try any solutions from answers?

Comment: Ya I tried that.. .built a new APK and sent it with the changes. Haven't received the feedback yet though :|

Answer (score 0):

Yes i am facing this type of error, worked below solution.Add below property into `AndroidManifest.xml's application tag`

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

**your xml file looks like this**

[image]